# Domain A record

Tags: hosting, dns, authentication

i've just added an A record for a domain to point to an ip address relating to another website which resides under a different domain - i own both domains and website.

the A record works in that if i enter the domain it goes to the correct ip address - however in safari and IE a dialog box pops up asking to enter username/password (specifically in safari it says "To view this page, you must log in to area X for site X:80") and there should be no logon - if you cancel you don't see the website and as i have no logon i can't see the website.

if i enter the websites original domain there is no prompt and works fine - if i enter the ip address directly in the browser it also asks for login.

the website (static pages) is hosted by fasthosts and doesn't appear to have any security settings around it or that can be set.

anyone know why one domain works and the other domain and ip address result in logon dialog ?

thanks
adam

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to DNS, but rather to web server configuration. Specifically to configuration of [**name-based virtual hosting**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting#Name-based).